# Unity3d with c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I would like to add a slider to my unity3d project, I am using c# script and the following code.

```
 public float hSbarValue;
 void OnGUI() {
         hSbarValue = GUI.HorizontalScrollbar(new Rect(25, 25, 100, 30), hSbarValue, 1.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F);
    }
```

This draws a slider that i have to use the mouse to drag it.

I want to turn it into a slider that moves on its own (like ping pong effect) until a button is pressed and then store the value in the `hSbarValue` variable.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hSbarValue = GUI.HorizontalScrollbar(new Rect(25, 25, 100, 30), Mathf.PingPong(Time.time*5.0f, 20), 1.0F, 0.0F, 50.0F);

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a Coroutine to increase the value of  it and kill the coroutine when the button is pressed. Something like:

```
IEnumerator IncrementValue() {
    while (true) { // Or a better limit
        hSbarValue += someIncrementValue;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // Or other value
    }
}

void Start {
    StartCoroutine("IncrementValue");
}

// later inside the button press handler
StopCoroutine("IncrementValue");
```

Comment: Works for me.  One note, the op mentioned something about a "ping pong" effect, your coroutine only ever increments so the slider never goes back to 0. (I'm assuming ping pong means back and forth)

Comment: @jerdak I didn't write code for him to use directly, obviously it would be necessary to modify it for his needs, in the case of a ping pong effect he'd need to check if it needed to be incremented or decremented. He can pay me to write exactly what he needs :P